# How to use at Query at this? - JPA repository spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> What I want to do is to get the total count in each month. So I have come up 
>   with these queries. I followed the documentation on Spring Boot JPA
>   repository using @Query. But when I run my app, it goes Application
>   Startup Failed. I dont know if my query is right.
>
> Here is my @Query

```
    @Query("SELECT MONTH(date_completed) FROM shipment WHERE YEAR(date_created)=?1 GROUP BY MONTH(date_completed)=?1")
public List<Shipment> findByDate_completed(String date);

@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shipment WHERE YEAR(date_created)=?1 GROUP BY MONTH(date_completed)=?1")
public List<Shipment> countByDate_completed(String date);
```

> Shipment.java

```
    package com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;


/**
 * Delivery of goods
 * @author JRDomingo
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="shipment")
public class Shipment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name="booking_number",unique=true)
    public String bookingNumber;

    @Column(name="wb_number")
    public String wbNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Vehicle vehicle;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Customer customer;

    public String origin;

    public String depot;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="vendor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Vendor vendor;

    public String type;

    @Column(name="commodity_type")
    public String commodityType;

    @Column(name="truck_type")
    public String truckType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Status status;

    @Column(name="delivery_date")
    public Date deliveryDate;

    @Column(name="fuel_po")
    public String fuelPo;

    @Column(name="client_ref_no")
    public String clientReferenceNumber;

    public String remarks;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="driver_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Personnel driver;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="helper1_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Personnel helper1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="helper2_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Personnel helper2;


    public enum Status{
        New, Dispatched, Delivered, Completed, Cancelled
    }

    /******
     * ACTUAL DATES IMPLEMENTED
     ******/
    @Column(name="date_created")
    public Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name="date_dispatched")
    public Date dateDispatched;

    @Column(name="date_completed")
    public Date dateCompleted;

    @Column(name="date_cancelled")
    public Date dateCancelled;

    @Column(name="date_received")
    public Date dateReceived;

    @Column(name="farthest_destination")
    public String farthestDestination;

    @Column(name="client_rate")
    public Double clientRate;

    @Column(name="is_sub_con")
    public boolean isSubCon;

    @Column(name="sub_con_rate")
    public Double subConRate;

    @Column(name="fuel")
    public Double fuel;

    @Column(name="fuel_amount")
    public Double fuelAmount;

    @Column(name="route_code")
    public String routeCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="dispatched_odometer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public RegularOdometerUsage dispatchedOdometer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="delivered_odometer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public RegularOdometerUsage deliveredOdometer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="completed_odometer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public RegularOdometerUsage completedOdometer;


    /**
     * index 0 = Driver , index 1 = Helper1, index 2 = Helper2
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="shipment",targetEntity=PersonnelRate.class)
    public List<PersonnelRate> personnelRates = new ArrayList<PersonnelRate>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Company company;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="prepared_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public User preparedBy;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_invoice", referencedColumnName="id")
    public CustomerInvoice customerInvoice;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="trucker_settlement", referencedColumnName="id")
    public TruckerSettlement truckerSettlement;

}
```

> What I want to achieve is to get the count of shipments with the status 'Completed' in each month based on the current year.

Comment: Firstly what is the exception you are getting. Put that. 
Secondly you should give more details about the problem. How does your Shipment class look like?

Comment: your queries not return Shipment they return int or long

Comment: @YCF_L, Could you correct that query? I am new to JPA.

Comment: did you tried `public long countByDate_completed(String date);` ?

Comment: @YCF_L - I tried but when I tried to run the app, it gives my this in the log

Application Failed to start . . . . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get a custom info from your db, for example, a month number and count of related records you cannot return a whole entity from the query method. You have to use a [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections). For example:

```
public interface MonthAndCount {
    Integer getMonth();
    Long getCount();
}

@Query("select month(s.dateCompleted) as month, count(s.id) as count from Shipment s where year(s.dateCompleted) = ?1 group by month(s.dateCompleted)")
List<MonthAndCount> getMonthAndCount(int year);
```

Note: it's important to use aliases (`as month` or `as count`) here to make the framework know how to fill you projection.

Test:

```
@Test
public void getMonthAndCount() {
    List<MonthAndCount> monthAndCount = repo.getMonthAndCount(2017);
    assertThat(monthAndCount).hasSize(4);
    monthAndCount.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Result:

```
{month=1, count=1}
{month=2, count=1}
{month=3, count=1}
{month=12, count=2}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `select *` operation in your hql query in that case hibernate can map your table data to your entity class but if you select custom fields by performing some operation those fields you need to create projection classes to map that data.

But if you do not want to create any class just to fetch data from query in that case you can use an `Object[]` instead of your entity class.

So your methods will simply look this

```
@Query("SELECT MONTH(date_completed), COUNT(*) FROM shipment WHERE YEAR(date_created)=?1 GROUP BY MONTH(date_completed)=?1")
public List<Object[]> findByDate_completed(String date);
```